# How to get the path/directory component from a NSURL?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsurl

I retrieved a NSURL from a NSSavePanel.  I now have this NSURL which gives me the following:

`file://localhost/Users/brett/Documents/asdf%20asdf.json`

Now, it is easy for me to retrieve just the filename using something like the following:

`[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] displayNameAtPath:pathAndFilename] stringByDeletingPathExtension]`

This gives me just the localized filename, as expected: `asdf%20asdf`

**So, how do I get the path, like so:** `file://localhost/Users/brett/Documents/`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could use `NSString` methods to work with file paths. For example,

```
NSString *directory = [[URL absoluteString] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
NSString *filename = [[URL absoluteString] lastPathComponent];
```

You could find other useful methods in Apple Docs: [NSString Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) -> **Working with Paths** section

Comment: I know that, as far as that filename goes, it isn't a localized string.  That's why I was using the displayNameAtPath: message to the NSFileManager.  Good answer though!

Comment: @Brett Anyway I think I answered on your question about getting file directory. Or what was you expecting?

Comment: You did answer correctly, I'm just scared using an NSString function instead of a NSURL function.  Maybe I shouldn't be.  Thanks!

Comment: @Brett I think you shouldn't ;)

Comment: I prefer to keep it in NSURL land as much as possible, too.  So, just use [URL lastPathComponent] instead.

Comment: Swift:  fileURL.absoluteURL.lastPathComponent! and fileURL.absoluteURL.URLByDeletingLastPathComponent!.absoluteString

Comment: @Nekto any example??  is have store my json path in string but it gives error null

Comment: `absoluteString` caused be some grief in that it sticks `file://` at the front and `NSFileManager-createDirectoryAtPath` doesn't like that.

Answer (score 37):

`-[NSURL URLByDeletingLastPathComponent]` is the simplest way to achieve this.

Comment: Much better than `NSString`.

Comment: Clarification: 
NSURL directoryURL = [fileURL URLByDeletingLastPathComponent];

Answer (score 1):

Directly from your NSSavePanel:

```
NSSavePanel *savePanel;
...
NSString *path = savePanel.directoryURL.path;
```